# How do I bind a ajax rating control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Specified cast is not valid.

```
 <tr>
                <td class="Bauto-style28">Price:
                    <asp:Label ID="lblprice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    Rating:       
                      <asp:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  StarCssClass="blankstar" 
        WaitingStarCssClass="waitingstar" FilledStarCssClass="shiningstar" 
        EmptyStarCssClass="blankstar" CurrentRating= '<%# Eval("ProductRating") %>' >
    </asp:Rating>
                </td>
                <td class="Bauto-style29">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CommandName="Add to wishlist" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'>Add to Wishlist</asp:LinkButton>

                </td>
```

Comment: Give some explanation at least. What is your value that try to cast?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the value of ProductRating is null or empty and the CurrentRating property cannot cast it to int.

Use

```
<asp:Rating
...
CurrentRating='<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("ProductRating").ToString())?0:Eval("ProductRating") %>'
```

Comment: ... means you get the same error message or what? What is the value of "ProductRating" field and what is its type? You can output it to a label control if you don't know.

Comment: 4 (int) and ya Specified cast is not valid

Comment: It should work then without any check. What do you get if instead of CurrentRating= '<%# Eval("ProductRating") %>' you set the value directly as CurrentRating="4" - it might be that the issue is somewhere else.